# How to force match Combobox RowSource row by setting its Text property?

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, autocomplete

On the shop floor, a virtual (touch) keyboard form with larger buttons is used to enter text into TextBoxes and ComboBoxes.

This works fine, and combobox text is set correctly, however the RowSource is not matched as it would be when you type directly into the ComboBox with a physical keyboard. The entire list is displayed as if you had just pressed the dropdown button without typing a character.

In the example below, there is a Stefan in the list, but that row is not looked up.

I've tried `SetFocus`, `Requery`, `Refresh`, `Dirty`, and calling `_AfterUpdate`, in combinations and with `DoEvents`, to no avail.

I've even tried to select, `Cut`, and `Paste` the text (but even setting `SelStart` and `SelLength` to correct values does *not* select it, so I'm assuming it cuts and pastes a range of zero characters). If I could make the text-selection work, I could probably get this to work.

```
Dim ctrlPrevious As Control
Set ctrlPrevious = Screen.PreviousControl
ctrlPrevious.SetFocus
ctrlPrevious.text = sTemp
ctrlPrevious.SelStart = 0
ctrlPrevious.SelLength = Len(sTemp)
ctrlPrevious.Cut
ctrlPrevious.Paste
```

**Is there a way to force the AutoComplete behavior?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SendKeys` to mimic the normal keyboard beheviour instead of all the above code.
So in your `btnPressed_Clicked` event

```
Dim ctrlPrevious As Control
Set ctrlPrevious = Screen.PreviousControl
ctrlPrevious.SetFocus   
SendKeys btnPressed.caption
```

Comment: Beautiful! So simple. I should have thought of it. But I stared myself blind on the control's methods instead.

Comment: Social Media power :)